# Retrieve the current version of the app from pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart

How will I access the current version of the app so that I can at least show in Text Widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the app version as an environment variable in your build config like so:

```
flutter build apk --dart-define=APPVERSION=1.0.0
```

then use it in the code like so:

```
const String APPVERSION =
String.fromEnvironment('APPVERSION', defaultValue: 'dev-build');
```

You can then use this in your text widget like so:

```
Text(APPVERSION),
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try out [package_info](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info) package:-**

```html
PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      var androidAppVersion = packageInfo.version;
      log("Android Version---->$androidAppVersion");
      log("Build Number---->${packageInfo.buildNumber}");
    } else {
      var iosAppVersion = packageInfo.version;
      log("Ios Version---->$iosAppVersion");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution addressing directly the version inside the `pubspec.yaml`:

```dart
class AppVersionWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  const AppVersionWidget({super.key});

  @override
  TabAboutInformationState createState() => TabAboutInformationState();
}

class AppVersionWidgetState extends State<AppVersionWidget> {
  late String appVersion = '?';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAppVersion();
  }

  Future<void> getAppVersion() async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

    setState(() {
      appVersion = packageInfo.version;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(appVersion);
  }
}
```